# Why does ARCore compiler errors with Unity3d?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools, arcore

I have downloaded the latest version of Unity version 5.6.1p1. Downloaded the ARcore for unity from the below website. 
https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/downloads

While trying to build the example, it gives the below compiler error:

```
Failed to extract `GoogleAR.UnityNative`. Config class of base type `UnityEngine.XR.Tango`. `TangoConfig` when inspecting `Assets/GoogleARCore/SDK/Plugins/GoogleAR.UnityNative.dll`
`UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper:ExtractAllClassesThatInheritMonoBehaviourAndScriptableObject(String, String[]&, String[]&)`
`Assets/GoogleARCore/SDK/Scripts/SessionComponent.cs(324,28): error CS7069:` Reference to type `UnityEngine.XR.Tango.TangoConfig` claims it is defined assembly `UnityEngine, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'` but it could not be found.
```

It will be good if I can get some pointers to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the latest Unity beta and check the box for ARCore in XRSettings.